# the destination address vs recipient's address

Tags: grammar

It is late in night and I am so tired.
I don't think I can get up early tomorrow morning, so I am writing a short message on a paper. Although the message is to be read by my little sister, I want to make use of this opportunity to learn and improve my English.
Here is what I am writing:

"MewMew,
I have written down the destination address on the envelope on your desk, 
but I can't find any postage stamps. Can you buy some for me?
Please put a new Christmas card and our letters into the envelope."

Are there any grammatical mistakes in the message?

Thank you.

Kitty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm restricted to a choice between the two, I would go with "recipient's address," though both would be understood.  However, a more natural way to say this in American English would be:

> MewMew, I have addressed the envelope on your desk, ---

I'm not sure how British English would treat this.

All of the rest looks great except for one other point that is more of an etiquette issue than a grammar issue.  I was taught that if a note addresses a person by name (MewMew, that is) then it should be signed as well.  Either your name or a short closing and your name would be appropriate.

> Please put a new Christmas card and our letters into the envelope.
>   (Thanks,) Kitty